# Login to scrape - getting an authenticity token but resulting html is for login page not target page - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

I am just beginning at this and for fun/practice I thought I'd attempt to automate the download the balance of my stock portfolio daily - storing the data somewhere and presenting it as a graph - a sort of 'try a bit of everything' personal project.

Anyhoo - to get to the value I need -  I need to login using email and password - the page also has an authenticity token (you can see it in the html) which I figured out how to harvest. I post my payload containing email, password and token, print the token (to check it changes each time and so is likely to be newly generated) then try to access the page with the daily balance and scrape the total.

What I'm getting at the moment is the original login page! As I said I'm new at this so it's kinda cobbled together from different examples I've come across.

Trouble is no errors - so it's a logic problem somewhere and as I don't fully understand what I'm doing I'm a bit lost.

Advice/solutions etc. gratefully received

Code is as follows:

```
import requests 
from lxml import html
import time
#open session
session_requests = requests.session()
#load info for login
payload = {
'email':'mymail@gmail.com',
'password':'mypassword',
'authenticity_token':'CSRF_TOKEN'
}
#describe login and portfolio balance page
login_url = 'https://dadada.com/login'
portfolio = 'https://dadada.com/my_one/portfolio'

#get login page
result = session_requests.get(login_url)

#obtain authenticity token
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]

#check authenticity token obtained
print(authenticity_token)

post = session_requests.post(
login_url, 
data = payload, 

)

time.sleep(20)

r = session_requests.get(portfolio)
print(r.text)`
```

Comment: In your GET request at the end you are only giving an url as parameter. My guess is, that you need to tell the `authenticity_token` to the server somehow. So that it knows, that it is still you. You could try to login in normal via your browser and check the `HTTP Headers` and your cookies on the `GET` after the login `POST`. Maybe the token is in a header or saved in some cookie which isn't the case in your code.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I had thought that by POSTing the authenticity_token as part of the payload I was advising the server. In a normal login there is an authenticity token included in the header.meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="xxxx" /> so I can add that as an additonal parameter to the get request? Will give it a try.

Comment: Haven't been able to make that work with headers = {'csrf-param':'authenticity_token', 'csrf-token':authenticity_token}
r = session_requests.get(portfolio, headers=headers) so no further ahead really.